# Embedding PHP if statements into HTML

Tags: php, html

feel like i have tried every possible way..right now it is just skipping over the if statement and posting out the html.

```
<? if ($departmentID == 1 :  ?>
    <h4>Outreach Questions <?= $departmentID ?><h4>
    <h4>Why Interested</h4>
    <ul>
        <strong>Why are you interested in volunteering as an outreach docent? </strong> <?php echo $whyInterested ?>
    </ul>

    <h4>Wildlife Issues</h4>
    <ul>
        <strong>What’s an environmental or wildlife issue you feel passionately about, and why? </strong> <?php echo $wildlifeIssue ?>
    </ul>
    <h4>Public Speaking</h4>
    <ul>
        <strong>Do you have prior experience speaking to the public? Please describe. </strong> <?php echo $publicSpeaking ?>
    </ul>
    <h4>Wildlife Groups</h4>
    <ul>
        <strong>Do you belong to any animal rights groups (PETA, The Humane Society, etc.)? If so, which ones? </strong> <?php echo $wildlifeGroup ?>
    </ul>
    <h4>Contributions</h4>
    <ul>
        <strong>What do you think you’d bring to the outreach volunteer team?</strong> <?php echo $bringToTeam ?>
    </ul>
<? endif; ?>
</div>
```

the idea is to do an else if with id ==2 and so on..but it is pushing out all the HTML regardless of the departmentID.

thanks in advance.

Comment: <? should be <?php Also, the filename should end with .php, not .html

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis after `if ($departmentID == 1`

Comment: Should the `</div>`s be inside the conditional?

Comment: @chris85 Probably not, since `<div>` isn't.

Comment: `<?= $departmentID ?>` shouldn't it be `<?php echo $departmentID; ?>`

Comment: @EvanCarslake That actually is fine (assuming OPs PHP version supports short hand echo). A `?>` will close the last statement.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but depending on how many conditionals and where they are nested divs might be causing the `pushing out all the HTML`.

Comment: @chris85 He says he's going to have a bunch of different `elseif` for different IDs. It looks like he just wants to put different lists inside a single `div`.

Comment: The elements inside `<ul>` should be `<li>`.

Comment: I fixed the closed parentheses with no luck...also whenever i switch it to <?php it wont even run the web page anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<?php if ($departmentID == 1) {`

`echo "  <h4>Outreach Questions = '$departmentID' </h4> #all html below`

`</ul>";}  # ends block and closes echo

?>
</div>`

Try this it uses php to echo out all of the html if the case is true otherwise no html gets echoed

Comment: also, make sure you properly close all of your tags your h4 on the first few lines isn't closed

Comment: it seems to just be echoing it out still.  I added a line of code to display what is getting pulled in by department ID and it is a 1.  I switched the if statemtn to if $departmentID != $departmentID then to echo the html.  (it should never echo), but it still displays the html...weird

Comment: so it seems to be just skipping over the if statement

Comment: UPDATE: this ended up working...i had to just mess with it a little but your format worked...thanks a lot

Comment: @mahoney if you could check off my answer id appreciate it :) i wouldve posted whole code but it only let me post a small bit

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the pretty first line wrong? You didn't close it:

Change the first line:

```
<?php if ($departmentID == 1) :  ?>
```